# Get number of rows returned in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble with a MySQL query I'm writing. I'd like to get a count of the number of rows that my query is returning without actually returning the rows and then using mysql_num_rows or the like.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(l.product_number_language) as counts, l.id, l.product_number, l.language,    l.product_number_language
FROM bs_products_languages l
LEFT JOIN bs_products p ON (l.product_number_language = p.product_number)
WHERE l.product_number = 'C4164' 
AND l.active='Y'
AND p.active='Y'
GROUP BY l.language
```

The following is what is being returned:
[image: Screenshot]

And what I really want is simply a count of these rows, so in this case 3.

Comment: You're not using `GROUP BY` correctly. If you want the `COUNT` of the result set, use `*_num_rows` (not `mysql_` functions).

Comment: Just to be clear, you would like to return these rows and include the total number of rows as well?  You don't want to return *only* the total number of rows, correct?

Comment: Returning only the total would be fine.

Comment: The accepted solution doesn't work always, what if I want to return the original query in a stored procedure and also want to log the number of rows returned each time this query is executed? I don't know how it is hard to have a simple system variable to return number of rows returned by the query.

Comment: New comment after 8yrs and 6mos, cool! The OP did say that the total number of rows based on the query is the only need, so that's the answer the OP got. If you want an answer that doesn't change the query, in a stored procedure and get something out to a variable similar to MSSQL but in MySql, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
Select count(*)
From
(
    SELECT COUNT(l.product_number_language) as counts, l.id, l.product_number, 
        l.language, l.product_number_language
    FROM bs_products_languages l
    LEFT JOIN bs_products p ON (l.product_number_language = p.product_number)
    WHERE l.product_number = 'C4164' 
    AND l.active='Y'
    AND p.active='Y'
    GROUP BY l.language
) as t
```

Comment: That works perfectly, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you, you've saved me a number of hours headache :)

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo, nice answer, it worked while other answers never worked.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thank YOU!

Comment: I don't think it is a brilliant solution, because I need to change the original query and do something extra to get a simple count of rows returned by my query. It is dead simple in SQL Server.. just use @@ROWCOUNT. You see the no of rows returned/affected in the output window when you execute any query in MySQL workbench, why can't we simply get that number via a system variable?